# can't get abstract class out of package object in scala

Tags: scala, abstract-class, java-package

I have a package object with an abstract class in it like this:

```
package mainPackage

package object subPackage {

    abstract class MyBase(val i: Int)
    case class DerivedClass(override val i: Int) extends MyBase(i)

}
```

In another file, I import the package:

```
import mainPackage.subPackage._
```

This gives me access to `DerivedClass`, but for some reason, I can't see the abstract base class. Any idea why? I want to create a `List[BaseClass]`, but it's not letting me.

Comment: Does this error occur only in your IDE or does your build system signal the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
package mainPackage

class Baba {
  import mainPackage.subPackage._

  new MyBase(1) {

  }

  val l: List[MyBase] = ???
}
```